# Best approach to model validation in PHP?

Tags: php, validation, model

I've learned that there are often many ways to solve one programming problem, each approach typically having its own benefits and negative side affects.

What I'm trying to determine today is the best way to do model validation in PHP. Using the example of a person, I've outlined four different approaches I've used in the past, each including the classes and a usage example, as well as what I like and dislike about each approach.

My question here is this: **Which approach do you feel is best? Or do you have a better approach?**

### Approach #1: Validation using setter methods in model class

#### The good

- Simple, only one class
- By throwing exceptions, the class can never be in an invalid state (except for business logic, ie. death comes before birth)
- Don't have to remember to call a any validation methods

#### The bad

- Can only return 1 error (via `Exception`)
- Requires the use of exceptions, and catching them, even if the errors are not very exceptional
- Can only act upon one paramater since other paramaters may not be set yet (no way to compare `birth_date` and `death_date`)
- Model class can be long due to lots of validation

```
class Person
{
    public $name;
    public $birth_date;
    public $death_date;

    public function set_name($name)
    {
        if (!is_string($name))
        {
            throw new Exception('Not a string.');
        }

        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function set_birth_date($birth_date)
    {
        if (!is_string($birth_date))
        {
            throw new Exception('Not a string.');
        }

        if (!preg_match('/(\d{4})-([01]\d)-([0-3]\d)/', $birth_date))
        {
            throw new Exception('Not a valid date.');
        }

        $this->birth_date = $birth_date;
    }

    public function set_death_date($death_date)
    {
        if (!is_string($death_date))
        {
            throw new Exception('Not a string.');
        }

        if (!preg_match('/(\d{4})-([01]\d)-([0-3]\d)/', $death_date))
        {
            throw new Exception('Not a valid date.');
        }

        $this->death_date = $death_date;
    }
}
```

```
// Usage:

try
{
    $person = new Person();
    $person->set_name('John');
    $person->set_birth_date('1930-01-01');
    $person->set_death_date('2010-06-06');
}
catch (Exception $exception)
{
    // Handle error with $exception
}
```

### Approach #2: Validation using validation methods in model class

#### The good

- Simple, only one class
- Possible to validate (compare) multiple paramaters (since validation occurs after all model parameters are set)
- Can return multiple errors (via `errors()` method)
- Freedom from exceptions
- Leaves getter and setter methods available for other tasks

#### The bad

- The model can be in an invalid state
- Developer must remember to call validation `is_valid()` method
- Model class can be long due to lots of validation

```
class Person
{
    public $name;
    public $birth_date;
    public $death_date;

    private $errors;

    public function errors()
    {
        return $this->errors;
    }

    public function is_valid()
    {
        $this->validate_name();
        $this->validate_birth_date();
        $this->validate_death_date();

        return count($this->errors) === 0;
    }

    private function validate_name()
    {
        if (!is_string($this->name))
        {
            $this->errors['name'] = 'Not a string.';
        }
    }

    private function validate_birth_date()
    {
        if (!is_string($this->birth_date))
        {
            $this->errors['birth_date'] = 'Not a string.';
            break;
        }

        if (!preg_match('/(\d{4})-([01]\d)-([0-3]\d)/', $this->birth_date))
        {
            $this->errors['birth_date'] = 'Not a valid date.';
        }
    }

    private function validate_death_date()
    {
        if (!is_string($this->death_date))
        {
            $this->errors['death_date'] = 'Not a string.';
            break;
        }

        if (!preg_match('/(\d{4})-([01]\d)-([0-3]\d)/', $this->death_date))
        {
            $this->errors['death_date'] = 'Not a valid date.';
            break;
        }

        if ($this->death_date < $this->birth_date)
        {
            $this->errors['death_date'] = 'Death cannot occur before birth';
        }
    }
}
```

```
// Usage:

$person = new Person();
$person->name = 'John';
$person->birth_date = '1930-01-01';
$person->death_date = '2010-06-06';

if (!$person->is_valid())
{
    // Handle errors with $person->errors()
}
```

### Approach #3: Validation in seperate validation class

#### The good

- Very simple models (all validation happens in seperate class)
- Possible to validate (compare) multiple paramaters (since validation occurs after all model parameters are set)
- Can return multiple errors (via `errors()` method)
- Freedom from exceptions
- Leaves getter and setter methods available for other tasks

#### The bad

- Slightly more complicated as two classes are required for each model
- The model can be in an invalid state
- Developer must remember to use the validation class

```
class Person
{
    public $name;
    public $birth_date;
    public $death_date;
}
```

```
class Person_Validator
{
    private $person;
    private $errors = array();

    public function __construct(Person $person)
    {
        $this->person = $person;
    }

    public function errors()
    {
        return $this->errors;
    }

    public function is_valid()
    {
        $this->validate_name();
        $this->validate_birth_date();
        $this->validate_death_date();

        return count($this->errors) === 0;
    }

    private function validate_name()
    {
        if (!is_string($this->person->name))
        {
            $this->errors['name'] = 'Not a string.';
        }
    }

    private function validate_birth_date()
    {
        if (!is_string($this->person->birth_date))
        {
            $this->errors['birth_date'] = 'Not a string.';
            break;
        }

        if (!preg_match('/(\d{4})-([01]\d)-([0-3]\d)/', $this->person->birth_date))
        {
            $this->errors['birth_date'] = 'Not a valid date.';
        }
    }

    private function validate_death_date()
    {
        if (!is_string($this->person->death_date))
        {
            $this->errors['death_date'] = 'Not a string.';
            break;
        }

        if (!preg_match('/(\d{4})-([01]\d)-([0-3]\d)/', $this->person->death_date))
        {
            $this->errors['death_date'] = 'Not a valid date.';
            break;
        }

        if ($this->person->death_date < $this->person->birth_date)
        {
            $this->errors['death_date'] = 'Death cannot occur before birth';
        }
    }
}
```

```
// Usage:

$person = new Person();
$person->name = 'John';
$person->birth_date = '1930-01-01';
$person->death_date = '2010-06-06';

$validator = new Person_Validator($person);

if (!$validator->is_valid())
{
    // Handle errors with $validator->errors()
}
```

### Approach #4: Validation in model class and validation class

#### The good

- By throwing exceptions, the class can never be in an invalid state (except for business logic, ie. death comes before birth)
- Possible to validate (compare) multiple paramaters (since business validation occurs after all model parameters are set)
- Can return multiple errors (via `errors()` method)
- Validation is organized into two groups: type (model class) and business (validation class)
- Leaves getter and setter methods available for other tasks

#### The bad

- Error handling is more complicated are there is exceptions thrown (model class), and an error array (validation class)
- Slightly more complicated as two classes are required for each model
- Developer must remember to use the validation class

```
class Person
{
    public $name;
    public $birth_date;
    public $death_date;

    private function validate_name()
    {
        if (!is_string($this->person->name))
        {
            $this->errors['name'] = 'Not a string.';
        }
    }

    private function validate_birth_date()
    {
        if (!is_string($this->person->birth_date))
        {
            $this->errors['birth_date'] = 'Not a string.';
            break;
        }

        if (!preg_match('/(\d{4})-([01]\d)-([0-3]\d)/', $this->person->birth_date))
        {
            $this->errors['birth_date'] = 'Not a valid date.';          
        }
    }

    private function validate_death_date()
    {
        if (!is_string($this->person->death_date))
        {
            $this->errors['death_date'] = 'Not a string.';
            break;
        }

        if (!preg_match('/(\d{4})-([01]\d)-([0-3]\d)/', $this->person->death_date))
        {
            $this->errors['death_date'] = 'Not a valid date.';
        }
    }
}
```

```
class Person_Validator
{
    private $person;
    private $errors = array();

    public function __construct(Person $person)
    {
        $this->person = $person;
    }

    public function errors()
    {
        return $this->errors;
    }

    public function is_valid()
    {
        $this->validate_death_date();

        return count($this->errors) === 0;
    }

    private function validate_death_date()
    {
        if ($this->person->death_date < $this->person->birth_date)
        {
            $this->errors['death_date'] = 'Death cannot occur before birth';
        }
    }
}
```

```
// Usage:

try
{
    $person = new Person();
    $person->set_name('John');
    $person->set_birth_date('1930-01-01');
    $person->set_death_date('2010-06-06');

    $validator = new Person_Validator($person);

    if (!$validator->is_valid())
    {
        // Handle errors with $validator->errors()
    }
}
catch (Exception $exception)
{
    // Handle error with $exception
}
```

Comment: wow you could of actully just done it and moved on 10 times it the time it took to do that, i'm guessing this isn't for a real work situation.

Comment: @ChrisCooney it's a good post with a very good question. +1

Comment: Sorry guys. Lots of repetition with slight code adjustments. Simpler than it looks. Just find that without clear code examples it's hard to get a proper answer.

Comment: people nowadays can't read anything longer than 160 characters it seems. and this post can be read and understood quite fast.

Comment: @Vucko I must admit, having read through it I spoke too soon. It's rare a question is formatted this well. +1 from me!

Comment: I'd use approach #1, with a slight change: `public function set_name(array $name)` I think PHP allows too much anyway (love it though lol).

Comment: @AmazingDreams string typehint in php?!

Comment: @AmazingDreams - **[Type hints can not be used with scalar types such as int or string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php)**.

Comment: Thanks, lol, but you got the idea (worked too much with C# lol).

Comment: @AmazingDreams Truth be told approach #1 is almost unusable for me, as I typically need to validation that compares multiple paramaters, which that approach doesn't (easily) allow.

Comment: This seems like an excellent question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Personally I like method 2, might be because I really like the Yii framework and that is basically how they do it. Only caveat is that you rarely need to call `is_valid()` or `validate()` or whatever you call it as it is built into the `beforeSave()` part of the class.

Comment: My comment to your question: In my opinion the usage must be as simple  as possible. Therefor your approach number two is the best way. But this is really no objective answer. Other people could like another approach. But i like the simple usage of approach two. The two approaches with exceptions are bad approaches in my opinion, because this aren't really exceptions but rather format checks. And the approach with two classes .. why two classes? Just for simple models? I don't really see any benefits? So, i would prefer approach number two.

Comment: @Pitchinnate Agreed, the usage code on method 2 is very nice.

Comment: @Cromax Solid points, and I totally agree on the exceptions, I don't like throwing them for this sort of things.

Comment: How about approach number five? Based on your approach number two or three, you can create a validator class with all your validator methods which works as a model base class. Your model class can inherit the validator methods from the base class?! This way you can define model classes in a very simple way, but have all your validators within your model.

Comment: @Cromax Sweet idea, but with no multiple inheritance support in PHP I'm not sure how great this would be. Users normally extend their models with some ORM. You could certainly still create a helper validation class that does your most common checks though.

Comment: I usually have generic validation methods in a base class (regex is wonderful). These methods are called before any transaction is done with the database - much like the `beforeSave()` method mentioned by @Pitchinnate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's just one best approach, it depends on how you are going to use your classes. In this case, when you have just a simple data object, I'd prefer to use **Approach #2: Validation using validation methods in model class**.

The bad things are not so bad, in my opinion:

> The model can be in an invalid state

Sometimes it's desirable to be able to have a model in an invalid state.

For instance, if you populate the Person object from a web form and want to log it. If you use the first approach, you'd have to extend the Person class, override all setters to catch exceptions and then you'd be able to have this object in an invalid state for logging.

> Developer must remember to call validation is_valid() method

If the model absolutely must not be in an invalid state, or a method requires the model to be in a valid state, you can always call `is_valid()` from within the class to make sure it's in a valid state.

> Model class can be long due to lots of validation

Validation code must still go somewhere. Most editors let you fold functions so that should not be a problem while reading the code. If anything, I think it's nice to have all validation in one place.

Comment: Good points, and I agree, the negatives are hardly bad. Really option #2 and #3 are the same, one just moves the validation into a separate class...and whether or not that has any benefits would be a personal choice. Option #2 also has the added benefit over #1 in that the getters/setters are free for other uses. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I don't think that this is a good solution in most cases because you tie the validation part to the otherwise "dumb" model itself. Models can have a different definition of "beeing valid" in another context. For example if you check postal codes for a country, it might follow other rules in other countries, With this solution you are totally unflexible. A separate mechanism validating the model decouples this responsibility. In my opinion, the class itself should not hold any validation logic.